# Moving Bottom Element Array to the Top: Index out of Range Error

Tags: swift

I am trying to move the bottom post in my array of posts to the top of my array of posts. I created the following code:

```
    self.posts.insert(contentsOf: tempPosts, at: 0)
    let element = self.posts.remove(at: tempPosts.endIndex)
    self.posts.insert(element, at: 0)
    let newIndexPaths = (0..<tempPosts.count).map { i in
            return IndexPath(row: i, section: 0)
        }
```

This code gives the error: Index out of range for the second line of the code chunk.

I tried the same code for moving elements, but I replaced `tempPosts.endIndex` with `tempPosts.endIndex - 1`. This works to move the second to last post in the array to the top. But when I change the code back to `tempPosts.endIndex`, it will not move the bottom post to the top of the array.

I tried adding the if statement:

```
 if self.posts.count > 2 {
        let element = self.posts.remove(at: tempPosts.endIndex)
        self.posts.insert(element, at: 0)
        }
```

But I got the same fatal error.

What is going wrong in my code and how can I trouble shoot it?

Comment: I tried similar operations in the playground and it works fine. The only case where I get the index out of range is when self.posts is empty to begin with.

Comment: See my edit: I tried an if statement to make sure self.posts has elements, and I still got an error even when self.posts has many elements

Comment: What is the length of self.posts before tempPosts is inserted at index 0?

Comment: Thanks guys. Leo's suggestion worked. self.posts was size 19 before inserting tempPosts. If he wants to write out the answer, I will give him the checkmark. If not, I'll write it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your intent is to move the last element of your collection to the beginning of it you can insert the resulting element returned by the `removeLast` method. Just make sure to not call this method if the array is empty:

```
posts.insert(posts.removeLast(), at: 0)
```

You can also extend `RangeReplaceableCollection` and create a custom method as follow:

```
extension RangeReplaceableCollection where Self: BidirectionalCollection {
    mutating func moveLastElementToFirst() {
        insert(removeLast(), at: startIndex)
    }
}
```

---

```
var test = [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1]
test.moveLastElementToFirst()
test  // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

---

```
var string = "234567891"
string.moveLastElementToFirst()
string  //  "123456789"
```